# Does R have dot notation like Python?

Tags: python, r

I am currently working on converting, refactoring, and optimizing a code base from R to Python.

The R code base uses the `source()` function a lot. From my understanding this is similar to importing a python file.

In python I can do the following: 
`import` *myFile* 
*myFile*.*some_function_or_variable_in_the_file*

Seems like you can not do this in R, which means I have to look at the R file in the `source()` function to know the functions and variables.

Also it seems like bad practice to be calling a function or variable from another file without `::` or `.` since this syntax indicates the file source to the left and the variable or function name to the right.

Maybe this is not as big of an issue when you are in R studio but I am working in Jupyter Lab for both the R and Python work.
It would be really nice if I did not have to always look at the files I was referencing.

Upon my google searches I found nothing. Any help or information would be helpful.

Comment: I think the term you are looking for is *namespaces*.

Answer (score 3):

`source` can import an R script into an environment and then the objects can be accessed by qualification.

```
myfile <- environment()
source("myfile.R", myfile)

myfile$fun(x, y, z)  # call fun from myfile passing x, y and z
ls(myfile) # show what was sourced into the myfile environment
```

Also look at the `sys.source` function, which provides a variation on `source` and also check out the box and import packages on CRAN.

Answer (score 1):

`source()` is as if you put the code of that sourced file into the same script/code. Everything in the sourced file - is in the same namespace - without distinction. So it is NOT comparable with `import` in Python.
Rather it is in Python `exec(open('filename').read())` or:

```
with open('filename') as f:
    exec(f.read())
```

In R, so far, you have to generate a package if you want to have a namespace.

## Defining the sourced file as an own namespace

I also found https://community.rstudio.com/t/is-it-dangerous-to-create-a-namespace-for-functions-in-a-script-without-a-package/91141

Where the function

```
source_as_ns <- function(namespace, file){
  ns <- namespace::makeNamespace(namespace)
  source(file, local = ns)
  base::namespaceExport(ns, ls(ns))
}
```

is given.
With

```
# script.R
foo <- function(x) x + 1
```

You can call:

```
source_as_ns("bar", "script.R")

bar::foo(1)
# 2
```

The answer from @G.Grothendieck works too - but it behaves less like a package, since the operator is `$` and not `::`.

Comment: Do you want to state that you can use `exec` to execute a python file with vary many functions in it and all those functions will be available as globals such that you could call them? I do not think this is correct. Check the solution provided above

Comment: `source` is technically comparable to `from ___ import *`.  if you just do `import __` thats the same as `source(...,___)`